# Is a Black Edition AMD processor required in order to unlock cores and/or overclock?

Tags: cpu, overclocking

As the title says, I'm planning on getting an ASRock N68C-S UCC board. It has unlock CPU core technology but would I need to have Black Edition processor in order to make use of that feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Black edition allows you to overclock by just changing the multiplier. You don't need a Black edition to unlock cores.

Answer (score 1):

No, you just need the right motherboard is all. My computer, which uses an AMD Athlon X2 CPU, can be overclocked with Windows software without rebooting, in no small part because I have an Asus M2N-E motherboard.

There's newer issues of this motherboard that will handle newer Athlon CPUs, but try searching the net for "motherboard for overclocking" and I'm sure you'll find what you're looking for.